# How to replace using wildcards in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

```
str = str.replace('?dfsdfsf=fdsfd.fdsfds/', 'uploads/')
```

i want to replace in url everything from '?' to first appearance of '/' afterwards ( including ) with 'uploads/'

instead of
https://websitename.com/?qqfile=somestrangefilename.jpguploads/d6113e4a-e789-44cd-8ba7-9684d29116dd.jpg

i want to get
https://websitename.com/uploads/d6113e4a-e789-44cd-8ba7-9684d29116dd.jpg

Comment: can you give any example, I mean what u want the result look like.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do that with javascript? Wouldn't it make more sense to do that server-side?

Comment: @Eric, no it wouldn't make more sense doing that server side in my case

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use regexp

```
str.replace(/\?[^\?\/]*\//, 'uploads/')
```

Comment: Just a note: No need to escape `?` in a character class.

Comment: @Qtax, thanks. And it appears that no need to escape `/` in a  character class either.

Comment: You do, since you are using slashes to quote the regex.

Comment: @Qtax, I thought so as well. But in console it works without escaping.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use a regular expression for this.

Try:

```
str = str.replace(/\?(.+)\//i, 'uploads/');
```

Explanation:

`\?` Finds the first `?`.
`(.+)` Finds any amount of any non-newline character.
`\/` Finds the last `/`
`/i` Tells the regular expression to be case insensitive, just for good measure.

Comment: that will replace everything until the last /, not the first

Comment: My apologies. However, the OP's example string only has one `/`, but we'll let them decide if this answer's correct or not.

Comment: +1 for the explanation, to have this match only till the first occurence of a `/` just add a `?` after the `+` to make it lazy `/\?(.+?)\//i`

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = '?dfsdfsf=fdsfd.fdsfds/';
str = str.replace(/(\?[^\/]+\/)/, 'uploads/');
```

[**Check it live**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/Lrcsb/)